# Bootstrap fixed sidebar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently experimenting with Twitter Bootstrap but I have a problem with my fixed sidebar.
When you hover over a menu item on the left, you can see that the menu doesn't stop where the content area starts. I don't really know how to explain it properly so I hope this is clear enough.

I'd like to know if there's a solution for this.

Comment: PLease insert code you have tried

Comment: The code should be on the example link I posted, I don't know exactly which part you need.

Comment: you shouldpost code you have in `index.html `

Comment: http://pastebin.com/gUXD2DhX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `CSS` as below

```
 #sidebar .nav {
          width: 95%;
          position: fixed;
 }
```

**to**

```
 #sidebar .nav {
          width: 10%; // change width as your choice
          position: fixed;
 }
```

you have select width of sidebar 95% of browser window.

Answer (score 1):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/RDgjL/)**

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">

    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
        <ul class="sidebar-nav">
            <li class="sidebar-brand"><a href="#">Fixed Menu</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 2</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 3</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 4</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <!-- Page content -->
    <div id="page-content-wrapper">
        <div class="content-header">
            <h1>
                <a id="menu-toggle" href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-success"><i class="icon-reorder"></i></a>
                Sidebar Fixed
            </h1>
        </div>
        <!-- Keep all page content within the page-content inset div! -->
        <div class="page-content inset">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <p class="lead">Resize window to see effect.</p>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
#wrapper {
  padding-left: 250px;
  transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
  margin-left: -250px;
  left: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  background: #000;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  z-index: 1000;
  transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}

.sidebar-nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 250px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.sidebar-nav li {
  line-height: 40px;
  text-indent: 20px;
}

.sidebar-nav li a {
  color: #999999;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:active,
.sidebar-nav li a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand {
  height: 65px;
  line-height: 60px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a {
  color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: none;
}

.content-header {
  height: 65px;
  line-height: 65px;
}

.content-header h1 {
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 20px;
  line-height: 65px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#menu-toggle {
  display: none;
}

.inset {
  padding: 20px;
}

@media (max-width:767px) {

#wrapper {
  padding-left: 0;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
  left: 0;
}

#wrapper.active {
  position: relative;
  left: 250px;
}

#wrapper.active #sidebar-wrapper {
  left: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
}

#menu-toggle {
  display: inline-block;
}

.inset {
  padding: 15px;
}

}
```

js

```
<!-- Custom JavaScript for the Menu Toggle -->

$("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#wrapper").toggleClass("active");
});
```